# Run command on the client during eb deploy

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My specific problem is that I would like to include the output of `git rev-parse HEAD` in a text file before deployment to ElasticBeanstalk. I believe the best way to solve it is to hook into the `eb deploy` command. I don't want to wrap `eb deploy` in a script.

I know .ebextensions defines commands that are executed on the ec2 instance during different phases of the deployment. Is there a similar utility for the client side?